How to retrieve image from s3 bucket and present it to the UI?
I am using a "API Gateway proxy integration" or "Lambda proxy integration". By having a handler file as:
import serverless from "serverless-http";
import app from "./app";

const handler = serverless(app);
export { handler };

My app.ts which contains my routs (shorter):
import express from "express";
import errorMiddleWare from "Utilities/error/handlerError";
import notFoundMiddleWare from "Utilities/error/notFound";
import helmet from "helmet";
import hpp from "hpp";
import cors from "cors";
import { getImage } from "routes/Get/getImage";

const app = express();
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));


app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*", // Allow all origins
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: false, // If your frontend needs to send cookies/token with the request
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Middleware for HTTP Parameter Pollution prevention
app.use(hpp());
app.use(`/api/media/`, getImage);


app.use(errorMiddleWare);
app.all("/*", notFoundMiddleWare);



export default app;

the route im focusing on is the getImage route which looks like this:
import { asyncMiddleware } from "Utilities/helper";
import { Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import path from "path";
import sharp from "sharp";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { PromiseResult } from "aws-sdk/lib/request";

const router = Router();
const isLocal = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

type ResizeResponse = {
  buffer: Buffer;
  type: string;
};

const resize = async (
  widthParam: string,
  imagePath: string | Buffer,
  imageName: string = "",
  s3Data:
    | PromiseResult<AWS.S3.GetObjectOutput, AWS.AWSError>
    | undefined = undefined
): Promise<ResizeResponse> => {
  let data: ResizeResponse = {
    buffer: Buffer.alloc(0),
    type: "",
  };

  try {
    const imageType = isLocal
      ? `image/${path.extname(imageName).substring(1)}`
      : s3Data?.ContentType || "application/octet-stream";

    if (widthParam) {
      // Resize the image to the requested width
      const width = parseInt(widthParam, 10);
      const resizedImage = await sharp(imagePath).resize(width).toBuffer();

      data = {
        buffer: resizedImage,
        type: imageType,
      };
    } else {
      // Serve the original image
      data = {
        buffer: imagePath as Buffer, // Assume `imagePath` can be treated as a Buffer
        type: imageType,
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing image:", error);
    throw new Error("Error processing image");
  }

  return data;
};

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.MYKEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.MYSEC,
  region: "eu-north-1",
  signatureVersion: "v4",
});

export const getImage = router.get(
  "/:imageName",
  asyncMiddleware(async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    const imageName = request.params.imageName;
    const widthParam = request.query.w as string;

    console.log("Request received:", {
      params: request.params,
      query: request.query,
      headers: request.headers,
    });

    if (process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME) {
      const bucketName = process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME;
      const s3Params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: `uploads/${imageName}`, // Adjust as needed
      };

      try {
        const s3Data = await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise();
        const imageBuffer = s3Data.Body as Buffer;

        console.log("S3 Data Retrieved:", {
          ContentType: s3Data.ContentType,
          ContentLength: s3Data.ContentLength,
          ETag: s3Data.ETag,
          LastModified: s3Data.LastModified,
        });

        console.log("Original image size (bytes):", imageBuffer.length);

        // Optionally resize if required, uncomment if needed:
        // const imageData = await resize(widthParam, imageBuffer, imageName, s3Data);

        const imageData = await resize(
          widthParam,
          imageBuffer,
          imageName,
          s3Data
        );

        console.log("Resized image size (bytes):", imageData.buffer.length);

        // Convert the image buffer to base64 if required
        // const base64Image = imageData.buffer.toString("base64")

        // Set the appropriate headers
        response.set("Content-Type", imageData.type);
        response.set("Content-Length", imageData.buffer.length.toString());
        response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        // Send the binary image data directly
        return response.send(imageData.buffer);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching from S3:", error);
        return response.status(404).send("No such image");
      }
    } else {
      return response
        .status(500)
        .send("S3 bucket name is not defined in environment variables");
    }
  })
);

export default router;

I have these two endpoints:
GetImages
media

This is a REST API and I am using AWS Lambda.
The flow here is simple: I hit the getImages endpoint, it fetches all my images from S3. Goes through them, fetches info about them from a db, build an object out of this and return it to the frontend.
The object looks like this:
const baseUrl = "https://myapp.com";
const modifiedKey = item.Key.replace("uploads/", ""); 
const dbdData = await getMediaById(modifiedKey);
const imageUrl = `${baseUrl}/api/media/${modifiedKey}`;

return {
          url: imageUrl,
          width: dbdData.width,
          height: dbdData.height,
          intrinsicSize: `${dbdData.width}x${dbdData.height}`,
       };

Not that the imageUrl points to the media endpoint.
So far this all works. Now when I want to render it in the frontend I would add something like:
<img src="https://myapp.com/api/media/420a7366-hsh73-4afa-b85e-b43a8ad540e6?preset=background" />

And this hits the media endpoint, fetches the image from s3 and reads the content type and returns it. Also it resized the image if I send in a width parameter, basically like this:
const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: `uploads/${imageName}`,
};

try {
    const s3Data = await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise();
    const imageBuffer = s3Data.Body as Buffer;

    const imageData = await resize(
      widthParam,
      imageBuffer,
      imageName,
      s3Data
    );
}

Return it:
    response.set("Content-Type", imageData.type);
    response.set("Content-Length", imageData.buffer.length.toString());
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    // Send the binary image data directly
    return response.send(imageData.buffer);

but I don't see my image, I see:

There are no errors or anything.
I have set my apiGateway to allow:
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - "multipart/form-data"
      - "image/*"
      - "application/octet-stream"
      - "*/*"

My logs show that I am returning buffer with right content type:
INFO    RETURNING {
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03 03 03 03 04 03 03 04 05 08 05 05 04 04 05 0a 07 07 06 ... 85223 more bytes>,
  type: 'image/jpeg'
}

I have noticed that the original byte size is 295956 but in the response it is 545448 i expect that the base64 encoding is doing this by default.
I don't know where I am going wrong here.

api gateway requires binary data to be Base64 encoded when returned from a lambda function. To handle this, ensure your lambda response is properly encoded and includes the isBase64Encoded property set to true.

Likely not an issue but be aware that AWS Lambda and API Gateway have payload limits of 6MB and 10MB respectively.

@jarmod  I am aware of this and my files are less than 2mb

@nabinsademba I am currently deploying with the base64 encoding to test.

@nabinsademba this will be an odd request but would you mind showing me how?
I did     const resizedBuffer = await sharp(imageBuffer).resize(parseInt(widthParam)).toBuffer();
res.set('Content-Type', s3Data.ContentType || 'image/jpeg');

// Send the binary data directly as the response
res.send(resizedBuffer.toString("base64"));


can you try sending just the
res.send(resizedBuffer);
and check if your binary support is turned on in your api gateway.@ThunD3eR

@nabinsademba just returning the entire object gave me {"buffer":{type:"buffer", data: [HUGE BUFF]}, "type":'image/jpeg'}

can you please paste your entire lambda here @ThunD3eR

@nabinsademba added the entire flow

Two important things; 1. Make sure that your client is also specifying the right content type in the Accept headers, i.e if your images have the content type image/png, then in the request to retrieve the image, make sure there's an "Accept: image/png" in the request headers. 2. Try to base64 encode your response and set isBase64Encoded in the response body, see how it's done here in AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html

@Tunmee Im not making a request such as with lets say Axios. I am putting this in the src attribute of a img tag. The reason I want to make this work like this is that if I paste the API url in the browser I want to return a image. If I encode it to base64 then it would be an URI which could work on my app but it would not render an image when i hit the backend url directly.
